# zkHost for using stream in standalone Solr?

Tags: solr

I try to use `stream` functionality of Solr,

```
http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr/ContentArticles/stream?expr=search(ContentArticles,qt=%22/export%22,fl=Title,sort=Title%20asc,q=%22Title:Iron*%22)
```

but I get the following error:

```
{
  "result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "EXCEPTION":"java.io.IOException: invalid expression - zkHost not found for collection 'ContentArticles'",
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":0}]}}
```

The [Reference Manual](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_11/stream-source-reference.html), zkHost is optional. I do not use zookeeper as it is a standalone Solr collection.

Where do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the stream functionality of SOLR is only available for cloud mode.
From the documentation:
"Streaming Expressions provide a simple yet powerful stream processing language for Solr Cloud."
From:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/streaming-expressions.html